# Apache Kafka Streams API vs KSQL

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I'm want to learn about the differences between the two methods. I developed a project so It aggregates some data using Apache Kafka Streams API. And after that, I got on some solutions which are written with KSQL.
I've never got experienced with KSQL so I would like to learn when and which approach should select for aggregate some stuff? Could I use KSQL instead of Kafka Streams?

Answer (score 1):

There's a blog post somewhere that talks about the "Kafka abstraction funnel"

KSQL doesn't provide as much flexibility as Kafka Streams, which in turn, abstracts many details of the core consumer/producer API.

If you have people more familiar with SQL, and not so good at other client libraries, you'd use KSQL. If you run into a feature not supported by KSQL (think, custom, complex data types) or need to embed streaming logic into a larger application without needing to remotely query the KsqlDB rest api, use Kafka Streams